# SQL query to display data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I searched it on SO, but I couldn't get a right answer.

```
Student
------------------
rollno int PK
name   varchar(20)
class  varchar(20)
```

The other table is

```
Marks
-----------------
rollno FK
sub1   int
sub2   int
sub3   int
sub4   int
sub5   int
```

`sub1`, `sub2`, etc. contain the marks of subjects. Now I want a query which will display student information who has >35 marks in more than 2 subjects?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As soon as possible format your question properly. You said you searched SO before so you have to know how proper formatting looks like. Besides provide sample data, desired output based on it, and your current version of the query.

Comment: Are u using sql server ?

Comment: Again provide sample data that show what you mean by *has > 35 marks in more than 2 subjects*. And what RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select rollno, 
 case when sub1 < 35  then 0 else 1 end +
 case when sub2 < 35  then 0 else 1 end +
 case when sub3 < 35  then 0 else 1 end +
 case when sub4 < 35  then 0 else 1 end +
 case when sub5 < 35  then 0 else 1 end +
 end 
 as [Count]
from student,marks where count > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN` and sum the fields that has more than 35.

```
SELECT s.rollno, s.name, s.class
FROM Student s join Marks m on (s.rollno = m.rollno)
where (CASE WHEN sub1>35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN sub2>35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN sub3>35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN sub4>35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN sub5>35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2;
```

You can check it from here [SQL Fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfd65/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tempRollnoTable(rno int)

INSERT INTO @tempRollnoTable
SELECT rollno FROM marks
WHERE sub1 > 35

UNION ALL

SELECT rollno FROM marks
WHERE sub2 > 35

UNION ALL

SELECT rollno FROM marks
WHERE sub3 > 35

UNION ALL

SELECT rollno FROM marks
WHERE sub4 > 35

UNION ALL

SELECT rollno FROM marks
WHERE sub5 > 35



SELECT * FROM student
WHERE rollno IN ( SELECT rno FROM @tempRollnoTable 
                  GROUP BY rno HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select student.* from student inner join marks on student.rollno= marks.rollno 
     where marks.rollno in(
      Select a.* from (
        Select RollNo from marks where sub1>35
        Union ALL
        Select RollNo from marks where sub2>35
        Union ALL
        Select RollNo from marks where sub3>35
        Union ALL
        Select RollNo from marks where sub4>35
        Union ALL
        Select RollNo from marks where sub5>35) a 
       having(rollno)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

your Marks table can be normalized first !

```
Marks
-----------------
rollno       int
Subject_ID   int --( FK )
Subject_Val  int

Subjects
-----------------
ID             int
Subject_Name   varcahar(20)
```

after you do this little change, things will become more clear

Answer (score -1):

I am new in coding too but u may try something like this but before always make the question  clearer

```
SELECT student.* from student InnerJoin marks ON studnet.roll_no=marks.student) where (sub1>=35 && sub2>=35 and so on)
```

Comment: syntax is incorrect and even the you are considering all the subjects to be greater than 35 which is not the case

Comment: Thnks I just misunderstood the question